# Arrow function in React update method

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a method to update the state of my component, that looks like this:

```
updateObject = (field) => {
  return (e) => {
    const obj = _.cloneDeep(this.state.obj);
    obj[field] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ obj: obj });
  };
}
```

I get an error `Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body` pointing at the first line. Why can't I have a block statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is valid.
This is intended behavior of the ESLint `arrow-body-style` rule. If return is the only statement inside the body of an arrow function, you do not need block statement.

```
updateObject = (field) => (e) => {
   const obj = _.cloneDeep(this.state.obj);
   obj[field] = e.target.value;
   this.setState({ obj: obj });
}
```

If you want to keep this style for your arrow functions, you can deactivate `arrow-body-style` rule.

Answer (score 1):

The correct code turned out to be pretty simple:

```
updateProject = (field) => (e) => {
  const project = _.cloneDeep(this.state.project);
  project[field] = e.target.value;
  this.setState({ project: project });
}
```

The block and the return statement is redundant.